Why is the message displayed twice? NASM
I'm writing a simple calculator in NASM, why when calling
jmp show_operands_message
Is the message printed twice into the terminal?
global _start

section .data
    selection_message db "Select operation (add, sub):", 10
    operands_message db "Enter operands: ", 10

    selection_message_count equ $-selection_message
    operands_message_count equ $-operands_message

section .text
    _start:
        jmp show_selection_message
        jmp show_operands_message
        jmp exit

    show_selection_message:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, selection_message
        mov rdx, selection_message_count
        syscall

    show_operands_message:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, operands_message
        mov rdx, operands_message_count
        syscall

    exit:
        mov rax, 60
        syscall


Output:
Select operation (add, sub):
Enter operands: 
Enter operands:

[Execution complete with exit code 1] 

The message is displayed twice, I tried setting the register values ​​to zero, but it didn’t help.
I would really appreciate your help!

selection_message_count equ $-selection_message is in the wrong place. It includes the length of the other message hence the double printing. Move it up to directly after the selection_message
